# How can I find which compatibility mode an H2 database is in?

Tags: h2

I know I can set a compatibility mode via SQL in H2, eg.

`SET MODE ORACLE`

Is there corresponding SQL to query which mode the database is currently in?

Comment: I don't think you can, why do you have such a requirement, how do you not know the mode?

Comment: Because I will need to run a query whose syntax will depend on the mode, and I don't know in advance what mode the database will be in?

Comment: You set it when you connect to the database, it's part of the database url, if you don't set it then it's just regular H2 syntax. You must have some very special use case if you don't know how you connect to the database. In any case I posted an answer.

Comment: Just to clarify (a long time later!) - my code will be passed a database connection by its caller, which will be a third party, and it has to handle whatever mode that third party gives it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'MODE';
```

Then make a **case insensitive** comparison to the different modes.